# Coq functional extensionality

Tags: coq

I have a goal with a function whose body I would like to rewrite, but
some of the function arguments get in the way of the rewriting.
I have recreated the situation with the identity function.

If the function is `Defined`, then it works, but when the function
is a parameter and I have an axiom stating how to rewrite, I'm
not able to rewrite.

I can only get it to work by assuming functional extensionality.
Is it possible to somehow rewrite without assuming functional extensionality?

```
Axiom functional_extensionality: forall {A B} (f g:A->B) , (forall x, f x = g x) -> f = g.

Variables A B : Type.
Variable f : A -> B.

Definition Id (x : B) := x.         (* here my function is Defined *)

Goal (fun x => Id (f x)) = f.       (* I'd like to rewrite inside the fun *)

Proof. auto. Qed.                   (* This works (eta reduction). *)

Variable Id' : B -> B.              (* Here I don't have the function definition *)
Axiom ID     : forall x, Id' x = x. (* only proof that it does the same thing *)
Goal (fun x => Id' (f x)) = f. 
Proof.
  rewrite ID.                       (* this doesnt work *)
  eauto using functional_extensionality, ID. (* but this works *)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible to prove this without assuming functional extensionality; Coq requires that `fun x => Id' (f x)) = fun x => f x` holds "definitionally".

What does "definitionally" mean here? Briefly, it means that both terms must have the same normal form *syntactically*. Recall that in Coq, every term has a normal form induced (mainly) by beta reduction.

However, we only know that `Id' x = x` "judgementally". Thus, Coq can't perform the reduction `Id' x ~> x`, preventing both terms above from becoming equal "definitionally".

This is indeed a limitation of Coq's theory, which I understand is in place so type-checking remains decidable.

Another approach to completing this proof would be to derive that the only function satisfying this equation is `fun x => x` (parametricity). This would provide you a hypothesis `Hid: ID' = (fun x => x)` which you could use to complete the proof. Unfortunately `Hid` is not provable internally in Coq.

Comment: But why can't one rewrite the left-hand side from `(fun x => Id' (f x))` into `(fun x => f x)` by using the axiom `forall x, Id' x = x` ?  What kind of inconsistencies could that cause?

Comment: The problem is more that Coq's theory is not powerful enough to perform the rewrite. It doesn't cause any inconsistency, that's why you can use functional extensionality safely (at the cost of not getting canonical proof terms anymore). I'll update my answer a bit.

Comment: @larsr, you cannot rewrite from `(fun x => Id' (f x))` to `(fun x => f x)`, this is invoking the function extentionality implicitly. The best you get is a endomorphic function in the function space `(A -> B) -> (A -> B)` which turns `(fun x => Id' (f x))` into `(fun x => f x)`. One of the current research topic in homotopy type theory is the computational meaning of function extensionality, you can check out how easy it is to "prove" function extensionality in cubical type theory: https://homotopytypetheory.org/2017/09/16/a-hands-on-introduction-to-cubicaltt/

Comment: Doesn't `Id' x ~> x` follow from beta-reduction?

Comment: That's the whole point @CuriousKid7, Coq cannot derive a computational rule "beta" from the ID axiom.